# Haskell: list of all non-identical unordered lists of up to n non-identical integers

Tags: list, haskell

I am trying to partition a set of words into equivalence classes of words of the same length, where a given character, say 'e', is in particular positions.

(I am trying to implement the Evil Hangman game which is specified here: http://nifty.stanford.edu/2011/schwarz-evil-hangman/.)

For example, given 'e', "feel" and "peel" would be in the same equivalance class, but "bed" and "eat" would not be. Words not containing the given character form their own equivalence class.

For each condition specifying such equivalence class, I will then count the number of words in the wordbank which satisfies it. (and then select the equivalence class of largest size)

At first, I considered using list comprehensions but I'm not sure how to specify to GHC what I want.

It would be nice, for example, to be able to do the following:

```
[[x1...xn] | x1,..,xn <- [1..10], xn> x(n-1) > ... > x1]
```

Where the xns form an ordered datatype ordered by their indexes. n is an arbitrary parameter.

Hence, I am hoping to receive suggestions on how I might proceed with deriving the lists I need for the creation of my conditions, by list comprehensions or otherwise.

Edit:

To provide additional details, here is the snippet of code I needed help on:

```
let countList = [(countSatisfy ((char, letterPositionList):listConditions) wordset , (char, letterPositionList) ) | letterPositionList <- foldl (++) [] (map (increasingSequences 0 (wl-1)) [1..(wl-1)] )  ]
let countAndSelectedList = getMaxCount countList
```

Using the following functions (thanks Daniel for the increasing sequence list function):

```
countSatisfy :: [(Char, [Int])] -> [[Char]] -> Int
countSatisfy listConditions wordset =
    foldl (+) 0 $ map (boolToBin . (foldl (&&) True)) (map (mapf (map checkCondTrue listConditions)) wordset)

getMaxCount :: [(Int, (Char, [Int]))] -> (Int, (Char, [Int]))
getMaxCount ((x1, y1):(x2, y2):xs)
    |x1 > x2 = getMaxCount ((x1, y1):xs)
    |otherwise = getMaxCount ((x2, y2):xs)
getMaxCount ((x, y):[]) = (x, y)
getMaxCount [] = error "No conditions satisfied"

mapf :: [(a -> b)] -> a -> [b]
mapf (f:fs) x = f x : mapf fs x
mapf [] _ = []

checkCondTrue :: (Char, [Int]) -> [Char] -> Bool
checkCondTrue (letterChar, letterPositionList) word = 
    (foldl (&&) True $ map (letterChar ==) (map (word !!) letterPositionList)) && (not (letterChar `elem` (removeItemsInPositionList (quicksort letterPositionList) word) ) )

increasingSequences :: Int -> Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
increasingSequences min max 0 = [[]]
increasingSequences min max count | max-min+1 < count = []
increasingSequences min max count = do
    h <- [min .. max]
    t <- increasingSequences (h+1) max (count-1)
return (h:t)
```

As is to be expected, this approach really suffers performance wise. I hadn't anticipated the combinatorial explosion resulting from multiple occurrences of a single letter. The code is also in pretty bad shape as this is my first program in Haskell.

Comment: I can't understand what you really want. The last list comprehenion amounts to "generate all the decreasing n-long lists", but this is only an example, you say. I can't see how this relates to the hangman discussed above. Can you elaborate? What is your actual goal? Given which inputs, what output do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
increasingSequences :: Int -> Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
increasingSequences min max 0 = [[]]
increasingSequences min max count | max-min+1 < count = []
increasingSequences min max count = do
    h <- [min .. max]
    t <- increasingSequences (h+1) max (count-1)
    return (h:t)
```

In ghci:

```
> increasingSequences 1 5 3
[[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,2,5],[1,3,4],[1,3,5],[1,4,5],[2,3,4],[2,3,5],[2,4,5],[3,4,5]]
```

Or like this, if you are just planning to use this to index into another list:

```
import Data.List

subsequencesOfLength n xs = go n xs where
    go 0 _ = [[]]
    go n xs = do
        h:rest <- tails xs
        t <- go (n-1) rest
        return (h:t)
```

In ghci:

```
> subsequencesOfLength 3 "abcde"
["abc","abd","abe","acd","ace","ade","bcd","bce","bde","cde"]
```

But it's not really clear to me how either of these will be useful. It sounds to me like you would much rather directly compute the defining characteristic of the equivalence class from a string and a letter, e.g.

```
type Class = [Bool]

classCharacteristic :: Char -> String -> Class
classCharacteristic c s = map (c==) s
```

Then producing all the equivalence classes is easy:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

classes :: Char -> [String] -> [[String]]
classes c ss = id
    . M.elems
    . M.fromListWith (++)
    $ [(classCharacteristic c s, [s]) | s <- ss]
```

In ghci:

```
> classes 'e' ["echo", "heal", "best", "lazy"]
[["lazy"],["best","heal"],["echo"]]
```

(I would probably even avoid defining `Class` and inline `classCharacteristic` if I were writing this myself -- splitting them out was just for pedagogy.)